# VBA scripting running slow

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am new at VBA. I need to run a code through out several worksheets (loop). However it is taking about 10 min to simply fill out a column. There is a lot of rows so it makes sense that the code will take some time, but it shouldn't take more than 3 min.

```
Sub Stocks():

    'Add columns where we will calculate the values
    For Each ws In Worksheets

      ws.Cells(1, 9).Value = "Ticker"
      ws.Cells(1, 10).Value = "Yearly Change"
      ws.Cells(1, 11).Value = "Percentage Change"
      ws.Cells(1, 12).Value = "Total Stock Volume"


    'Create a loop to search the next different value on column A and print it on Column I

    Dim ticker_row As Double
    ticker_row = 2

    LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow

        If ws.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> Cells(i, 1).Value Then

        ticker_symbol = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        ws.Range("I" & ticker_row).Value = ticker_symbol
        ticker_row = ticker_row + 1

        End If

    Next i

    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: If I'm understanding your code correctly, you don't need a loop at all. You could simply use a formula with an `IF()` to accomplish this, and it will execute much faster than the loop you're currently using. Also, VBA (the scripting language used in MS Office applications) is not VBScript (the command-line scripting language), and neither of those are the same as VB6 or VB.Net. Just because they start with VB does not make them the same, any more than a cat and a car and a carrot are the same because they all start with *ca*. Please don't randomly add tags.

Comment: Couldn't you accomplish this with a simple filter? Ribbon's *Data* tab > *Sort & Filter* > *Advanced* then check "Copy to another location* , enter source and destination ranges, the destination as the same size range as the source, and check *Unique records only*

Comment: Is your data sorted on Column A ?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, it is sorted on column A

Comment: @KenWhite Column A has a 100 sets of values , the first set of values contains the word "A" for all the dates of a year (column B), then the second set of values contain the word "AA" (Column A) for the same dates of the year (Column B). I use a loop to make the calculation for each of the sets, I need to do the calculation every time the value on column A changes. I am not sure how to do that using only IF(). In addition, thanks a lot for the explanation. The READ ME of my homework says: "In this homework assignment you will use VBA scripting to analyze real stock market data"

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue for new VBA programmers. VBA is extremely slow at looping through ranges. Every time you read a value from a range and every time you write a value to a range takes a lot more processing time than you would expect.

However, reading a large range into an array variable in VBA counts as only one read action, looping through an array in VBA is extremely fast, and writing a large array back to a range in Excel also counts as only one write action. Making this change would probably result in your code taking about 1 to 2 seconds to run.

There are lots of websites that go into great detail on how to read a range of values into an array variable and do processing in VBA, before writing the results back to Excel. Google: "VBA Loop Through Array"

A good couple of references are:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx

https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/

Answer (score 0):

When you interact with the Excel Object Model it can be very slow.  There are two things that dramatically slow things down 1. refreshing the screen after each cell interaction, and 2. recalculating the worksheet after each cell interaction.  Your code does not seem to be doing any calculating, but you are interacting with the screen.  I suggest you wrap your code with the following:

Beginning of all your code

```
   'Turn off screen updating and auto recalc
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

At end of all your code

```
    'Turn screen updating and auto recalc back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

If you want to get fancy, you can set a variable to store the Application.Calculation current value and set it back to the starting value when done

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Stocks():

    Dim ticker_row As Long, data, ws As Worksheet, currentticker, i As Long

    'Add columns where we will calculate the values
    For Each ws In Worksheets

        ws.Cells(1, 9).Value = "Ticker"
        ws.Cells(1, 10).Value = "Yearly Change"
        ws.Cells(1, 11).Value = "Percentage Change"
        ws.Cells(1, 12).Value = "Total Stock Volume"

        'get the data in a 2D array
        data = ws.Range(ws.Range("A2"), _
                        ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value

        ticker_row = 2

        currentticker = Chr(0)
        'loop over the array and check for new ticker value
        For i = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
            If data(i, 1) <> currentticker Then
                'new ticker - add to list
                ws.Range("I" & ticker_row).Value = data(i, 1)
                ticker_row = ticker_row + 1
                currentticker = data(i, 1)
            End If
        Next i

    Next ws

End Sub
```